# Data doesn't stay in firebase if read by the terminal it has to

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I've an app where a pair of devices communicate with each other, the communication successfully happens, but when they read the data put by the other it automatically deletes all firebase realtime entries that get created, except the last one.

This looks to happen just by the mere fact of reading them I mean I've a code like this:

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Chat").child("id").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                                if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {

                            (Use the snapshot and nothing else)
```

That for some reason looks like it ends up deleting the original entry.

Also entries that are not read by any terminal always keep in firebase all the time as long as they are not deleted on purpose, so it looks like the fault is in the read part.

What could I do so all messages I want not to be deleted stay when a read happens?

Comment: Nothing that you've shown here will cause data to be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

```
  FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Chat").child("id").addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot ds, @Nullable String s) {
            Message value = ds.getValue(Message.class);
            messageEntries.add(value);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

- this the right way to read data from realtime database